# Decay estimates for the derivatives of the solutions to the heat equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Let $u$ be the solution of the Cauchy problem for the heat equation with initial datum $u_0 \in L^1 \cap L^p$. Then I know that the following estimates hold: 
$$\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^p} \le Ct^{-\frac{N}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}\Vert u_0\Vert_{L^1}$$
$$\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^p} \le Ct^{-\frac{N}{2}\left(\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{p}\right)}\Vert u_0\Vert_{L^q}$$
and $$\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^p} \le \Vert u_0 \Vert_{L^p}$$
where $N$ is the space dimension, $p \in [q,\infty)$ and $C$ a constant.

Let $q \in [1,2]$, and $u_0 \in L^q$
I'm not able to prove the following estimate  (which should be classical)
$$\Vert \partial^k_t D^\alpha u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^p} \le Ct^{-\frac{N}{2}\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}\right)-\frac{|\alpha|}{2} - k}\Vert u_0\Vert_{L^q},$$
where $p \in [q,\infty)$, $C$ is a constant, and $|\alpha|$ is the lenght of the multi-index $\alpha$.
How does one do it?

I've tried to compute
$$\partial_{x_k} K(t,x) = \frac{-x_k}{t}K(t,x)$$
$$\partial_{x_kx_k} K(t,x) = \left(\frac{x^2_k}{t^2}- \frac{1}{t}\right)K(t,x)$$
$$\partial_{t} K(t,x) = \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{|x|^2}{t^2}- \frac{N}{t}\right)K(t,x)$$

(where $K$ is the heat kernel), but I don't see where this leads.

Comment: $L^p$ of what? What is the spatial region?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$

Comment: So you can work with the Heat kernel. Have you tried that?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts As I've written at the end of the questions, I've tried some computations, but I don't see where they lead.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts The problem is closely related to another question of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335491/prove-left-partial-t-frac14-pi-t2ne-fracx24t-right-le

Comment: maybe this book helps a bit: https://uploadfiles.io/8p5zm