# Prove $\left|\partial_t \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{2N}}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}\right| \le \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{2N}} C \frac{e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}}{t}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. How can I prove that the following estimates hold?

$$\left|\partial_t \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{2N}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}\right| \le C \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{2N}} \frac{e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}}{t}$$
$$\left|\partial_{x_k} \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{2N}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}\right| \le C \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{2N}} \frac{e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}}{\sqrt{t}}$$
$$\left|\partial^2_{x_kx_h} \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{2N}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}\right| \le C \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{2N}}  \frac{e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}}{t},$$
where $C$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be very hard, because they are not true. Consider the second one:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\bigl(e^{-|x|^2/(4t)}\bigl)=-\frac{x_k}{2\,t}\,e^{-|x|^2/(4t)}=-\frac{x_k}{2\,\sqrt t}\,\frac{e^{-|x|^2/(4t)}}{\sqrt t}.
$$
If the second inequality were true, we would have
$$
\Bigl|\frac{x_k}{2\sqrt t}\Bigr|\le C,
$$
which clearly cannot hold for all $x$ and $t$. However, it would hold on a parabolic region of the form $|x|\le C\,\sqrt t$.

Comment: Thanks. I've another question that is basically the same, but about $L^p$ norms of the derivatives. Would you have a look at it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335201/decay-estimates-for-the-derivatives-of-the-solutions-to-the-heat-equation

Comment: I checked: those estimates should be correct as they appear in Ladyzhenskaya-Solonnikov-Uraltseva book on parabolic PDE (chapter 4, section 13). I cannot follow their proof though, and the estimates do seem strange.